# Print fetch outputs in react native

Tags: loops, react-native, render

i tried to print my fetch outputs and i got error
this is my code:

```
sliderRender(info) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainCarouselView}>
            <Image style={styles.mainCarouselImage} source={{uri: info.sliderImg}} />
            <View style={styles.mainCarouselOverlay}>
                <Text style={styles.mainCarouselTitle}>{info.specialTitle}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

getSlider() {
    fetch(GLOBALS.API + '/specials.php?action=getSlider&key=' + GLOBALS.KEY)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        var output = [];
        let response = responseJson.response;
        if(response instanceof Array && response.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                output.push(this.sliderRender(response[i]));
            }
            try {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('slider', JSON.stringify(output));
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error when we set local storage " + error.toString());
            }
        }

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.toString());
    });
    try {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('slider', (err, result) => {
            let slider = JSON.parse(result);
            this.setState({
                sliderOp: slider
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error by get item " + error.toString());
    }
}

showSlider() {
    var Carousel = require('react-native-carousel');
    if (this.state.sliderOp !== null) {
        return (
            <Carousel
                style={styles.mainCarousel}
                hideIndicators={true}
                animate={false}>
                {this.state.sliderOp}
            </Carousel>
        );
    }
}
```

what i am tried its to store the fetch outputs to array like this:

```
output.push(this.sliderRender(response[i]));
```

and store it in state and in the end to print the state...
but the error is that:

```
"objects are not valid as a react child"
```

what can i do?

tnx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The code you provided is not complete so it's hard to understand where the error is actually happening, but, according to the error, it seems that "info.specialTitle" is an object and not a string.</strike>

--Edit--

Sorry, I was wrong before.
It seems like you're trying to save the entire View structure to AsyncStorage. This is not possible. You should only save to AsyncStorage your own text data (in json format if you want). JSX converts the View to a lot more complicated object with possibly circular structure which you can't (and shouldn't) save in AsyncStorage.

Try saving the data u receive and then render the slider like so (untested):

```
sliderRender(info, key) {
    return (
        <View key={key} style={styles.mainCarouselView}>
            <Image style={styles.mainCarouselImage} source={{uri: info.sliderImg}} />
            <View style={styles.mainCarouselOverlay}>
                <Text style={styles.mainCarouselTitle}>{info.specialTitle}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

getSlider() {
    fetch(GLOBALS.API + '/specials.php?action=getSlider&key=' + GLOBALS.KEY)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        var output = [];
        let response = responseJson.response;
        if(response instanceof Array && response.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                output.push(response[i]);
            }
            try {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('slider', JSON.stringify(output));
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error when we set local storage " + error.toString());
            }
        }

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.toString());
    });
    try {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('slider', (err, result) => {
            let slider = JSON.parse(result);
            this.setState({
                sliderOp: slider
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error by get item " + error.toString());
    }
}

showSlider() {
    var Carousel = require('react-native-carousel');
    if (this.state.sliderOp !== null) {
        const sliderOps = this.state.sliderOp.map((op, i) => this.slideRender(op, i));
        return (
            <Carousel
                style={styles.mainCarousel}
                hideIndicators={true}
                animate={false}>
                {sliderOps}
            </Carousel>
        );
    }
}
```